# How to evaluate variables in fish

Tags: command-line-interface, fish

I'm trying out the fish shell, coming from zsh and bash. I'm sorely missing the `$_` positional parameter, and am attempting to imitate it with a function.

Fish contains its command-history in a `$history` array, where `$history[1]` is the previous line in history, `$history[2]` is the one before that, and so on.

I am attempting to evaluate this variable and extract the last word like this

```
ls -al
echo $history[1] | awk '{print $NF}'         // Prints -al
```

I have tried putting it in a function like this

```
function \$_ --description 'Fish-patch for the $_ positional parameter'
    echo $history[1] | awk '{print $NF}'
end
```

But it doesn't quite work as expected. Calling `$_` by itself works as expected;

```
ls -al
$_
```

It prints `-al`. But if `$_` is passed as a parameter to a function;

```
ls -al
echo $_
```

It prints `echo`. I suspect it has something to do with the `$_`-function being evaluated in a subshell or something, I really don't know.

What is wrong here? Why doesn't `echo $_` work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fish, `$_` is a read-only variable containing the last foregrounded job. However you could use `$__` or a different character.

The simplest option is to just update `$__` after every command:

```
function update_last_arg --on-event fish_postexec
    set -g __ (echo $argv | awk '{print $NF}')
end
```

now `$__` will always contain the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

because fish does not have global aliases. The arguments you give to `echo` are just strings, they don't get evaluated as code.

You'll have to do this, which reduces it's usability.

```
echo ($_)
```

I found (somewhere) a method of implementing the bash history-like `!!` and `!$`:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind ! bind_bang
    bind '$' bind_dollar

    # enable editing command line in editor with Alt+v
    bind \ev bind_edit_commandline
end
function bind_bang
    switch (commandline -t)[-1]
    case "!"
        commandline -t $history[1]; commandline -f repaint
    case "*"
        commandline -i !
    end
end
function bind_dollar
    switch (commandline -t)[-1]
    case "!"
        commandline -t ""
        commandline -f history-token-search-backward
    case "*"
        commandline -i '$'
    end
end
```